# NAT for IPSEC access?

Tags: iptables, vpn, routing, openvpn

Please help to understand if the following configuration can be created.

1. I have IPSEC connection with my customer. It is site2site vpn between customer network and my network 10.102.103.0/28. This connection is established between my VPN node with IP 10.102.103.7/28 and customer VPN node. OpenSwan is used for it.
2. VPN node is located on Amazon and I use OpenVPN to access Amazon. OpenVPN gives me IP in own network 192.172.3.0/28.

Is it possible to get an access to customer network from OpenVPN network? Can I access customer's network if my client IP is 192.172.3.5 for example? As I understand and as I can see IPSEC drops all my packet from OpenVPN network to customer's network, since my IP is out of 10.102.103.0/28.

Is there any good solution to fix it? Or workaround?